# Show that if $R$ is an integal domain, then $R[X]$ is an integral domain.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ denote an integral domain, and $R[X]$ denote the polynomials over $R$. Show that $R[X]$ is an integral domain.

---

All I've got left is the non-trivial part - i.e. the cancellation property of $R[X]$. Equivalently, the non-existence of zero divisors. However, I have no idea how to proceed! A hint, please?

Edit: Okay, I need a bit more help. I get that for every $f \in R[X]$, there exists a sequence $a : \{0,\cdots,n\} \rightarrow R$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x \in R$ it holds that $f(x)=\sum_{i \in n}a_ix^i.$ Is such a sequence necessarily unique? If so, I can do the rest of the proof myself.

Comment: $a:\{0,\dots,n\}\to R$, not $\to R[X]$.

Comment: And yes, such a sequence is unique.

Comment: How are you defining $R[X]$, by the way?

Comment: Also i dont know how its being defined, the lecture notes are strangely silent about this.

Comment: No textbook or other class materials?

Comment: Ive got artin at home, so ill check that out when i get home.

Comment: The important thing to realize about the ring $R[X]$ is that the polynomials are not functions. For example, when $R=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, while it is true that $r^3-r=0$ for all $r\in R$, that does not mean that the polynomial $X^3-X$ is zero in $R[X]$. Rather, $X^3-X$ has an indeterminate $X$.

Comment: Okay. What do we call the function that a polynomial gives rise to?

Comment: Given a $p(X)\in R[X]$ the map it defines $R\to R$ is called a polynomial function.The nice thing is that when we have a homomorphism $R\to R'$ we can evaluate $p(X)$ on $R'$, too.

Comment: @user18921 By definition, the function $\rm\ f : \Bbb N\to R\ $ *is* the polynomial. They are added pointwise $\rm\:(f+g)(n) = f(n)+g(n)\:$ and multiplied by convolution $\rm\ (fg)(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n f(k)g(n\!-\!k).\:$ Equality is simply equality of functions, i.e. $\rm\:f = g\iff f(n)=g(n)\:$ for all $\rm\:n\in \Bbb N,\:$ i.e. polynomials are equal iff they have equal coefficient sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the coefficients of the terms of highest degree.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the coefficient of the highest power in a product of two nonzero polynomials. It must be nonzero because R is an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n,g(x)=b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_mx^m$. If these are not $0$, then we can assume $a_n,b_m\ne 0$. Thus the highest-degree term of $f\cdot g$ is $a_nb_mx^{n+m}\ne 0$, so $f\cdot g\ne 0$. Thus $R[X]$ has no zero divisors.